# OpenGL Output Window shrinks to 0 x 0 window immediately

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glut

I have a problem with OpenGL programs using OpenGLUT that are compiled and run in Visual Studio 2012. The program compiles fine and when I press run an 800 x 600 window opens and displays the image that I want. However, the window immediately begins shrinking until it reaches 0 x 0 in about 2 seconds and then stays open. I'm not quite sure what the problem is and Google searches turned up no relevant information. Here are some screenshots of the problem:

[image: This is a screenshot immediately after the program started.]

The above screenshot was taken immediately after the program started. The below screenshot was taken about a second after the program started without any interaction from me.

[image]

The output window continues to shrink until it is 0 x 0 size. Here is my code and any suggestions would be helpful.

```
#ifdef __APPLE_CC__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <OpenGlut.h>
#endif

// Clears the window and draws the tetrahedron.  The tetrahedron is  easily
// specified with a triangle strip, though the specification really isn't very
// easy to read.
void display() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Draw a white grid "floor" for the tetrahedron to sit on.
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  for (GLfloat i = -2.5; i <= 2.5; i += 0.25) {
    glVertex3f(i, 0, 2.5); glVertex3f(i, 0, -2.5);
    glVertex3f(2.5, 0, i); glVertex3f(-2.5, 0, i);
  }
  glEnd();

  // Draw the tetrahedron.  It is a four sided figure, so when defining it
  // with a triangle strip we have to repeat the last two vertices.
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1); glVertex3f(0, 2, 0);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex3f(-1, 0, 1);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1); glVertex3f(0, 0, -1.4);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1); glVertex3f(0, 2, 0);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex3f(-1, 0, 1);
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
}

// Sets up global attributes like clear color and drawing color, enables and
// initializes any needed modes (in this case we want backfaces culled), and
// sets up the desired projection and modelview matrices. It is cleaner to
// define these operations in a function separate from main().
void init() {

  // Set the current clear color to sky blue and the current drawing color to
  // white.
  glClearColor(0.1, 0.39, 0.88, 1.0);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  // Tell the rendering engine not to draw backfaces.  Without this code,
  // all four faces of the tetrahedron would be drawn and it is possible
  // that faces farther away could be drawn after nearer to the viewer.
  // Since there is only one closed polyhedron in the whole scene,
  // eliminating the drawing of backfaces gives us the realism we need.
  // THIS DOES NOT WORK IN GENERAL.
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glCullFace(GL_BACK);

  // Set the camera lens so that we have a perspective viewing volume whose
  // horizontal bounds at the near clipping plane are -2..2 and vertical
  // bounds are -1.5..1.5.  The near clipping plane is 1 unit from the camera
  // and the far clipping plane is 40 units away.
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum(-2, 2, -1.5, 1.5, 1, 40);

  // Set up transforms so that the tetrahedron which is defined right at
  // the origin will be rotated and moved into the view volume.  First we
  // rotate 70 degrees around y so we can see a lot of the left side.
  // Then we rotate 50 degrees around x to "drop" the top of the pyramid
  // down a bit.  Then we move the object back 3 units "into the screen".
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);
  glRotatef(50, 1, 0, 0);
  glRotatef(70, 0, 1, 0);
}

// Initializes GLUT, the display mode, and main window; registers callbacks;
// does application initialization; enters the main event loop.
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowPosition(80, 80);
  glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
  glutCreateWindow("A Simple Tetrahedron");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  init();
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: +1 for a truly unique bug :-)

Comment: is there a small enough amount of code to post the whole thing, because there is not enough information right now.  if its on source control, feel free to link that

Comment: Fascinating... `display()` is the only GLUT callback you have registered? No reshape callback, or anything like that?

Comment: Yep, display() is the only callback provided to glut. Also the code I provided was just a sample provided by a professor. I reproduced the same problem again when I drew a simple white triangle on black background. This problem was not present when compiled and run on a Linux machine. So I believe the problem is with the GLUT API interfacing with the Windowing system.

Comment: Yes, I doubt this has anything to do with the rendering at all. You would probably see the same thing with just the `glClear()`. What flags are you passing to `glutInitDisplayMode()`? If they include `GLUT_DOUBLE` (which is strongly recommended), you need a `glutSwapBuffers()` instead of the `glFlush()` at the end of `display()`.

Comment: What happens when you migrate from OpenGLUT (which AFAIK is not actively maintained at the moment) to FreeGLUT which offers the same API and then same more and is actively maintained. This is pretty much a bug in your GLUT implementation.

Comment: datenwolf- you sir are a lifesaver. I removed all openGlut files and added in freeGlut instead. Everything works perfectly now! Please paste your comment into an answer, so I can give you credit.

Comment: This was very misleading. The question says clearly that you were using FreeGLUT all along, and it has the FreeGLUT tag. I guess the name of the header file gave it away, but questions should really clearly specify your configuration.

Comment: @RetoKoradi You're right, I should have paid more attention to the verbage and apparently I couldn't tell the two apart in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution - abandon GLUT. I recommend you to use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) instead.

GLFW:

- Has more features.
- Is simpler.
- Has a better designed API.
- Is modern and is beign actively developed.
- Has a very good documentation.
- Just works.